# Website is online but isn't responding to connection attempts

Tags: browser, webserver, website

I have a small website hosted on Godaddy.com

Today I had an unpleasant experience, although everything worked fine until the first half of the day, then after I tried to open my website on my Windows 10 Desktop, all browsers returned same error: **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**

I tried to flush network settings, turn off firewall, clear cache, run incognito browser session, restart of PC, turn on/off WiFi, power reset router, but nothing helped.

The strange thing is that I can open my website from other device on same HOME network, but website is loading a bit slower than usually, but it opens. I can access it from mobile using mobile internet, and also I have a feeling like it is loading a bit slower than usually, but works.

I tried to loggin to my CPanel and find if website is blocked, but from IP Blocker tool I cannot see any IP being blocked.

Windows traoubleshooter says this:

> The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 80,
>   possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it
>   might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn’t find any problems
>   with the firewall on your computer.

I tried to check the network traffic with WireShark and I can see that requests are sent to the right server IP address but no requests comes back.

Then I opened a virtual machine with VMware and tried to open my website in a web browser, and without success, network adapter connection was set to NAT. Then I changed connection to NAT and Custom, with no luck, **BUT THEN after I set adapter connection of VMware to Bridged, after few second I was able to load my website in browser inside virtual machine.**

So, what is wrong ? Please point me to the possible solutions...

Comment: Are you hosting this on your home PC using a GoDaddy DNS?

Comment: @Cris I'm hosting it on Godaddy's economy shared web hosting

Comment: Then why haven't you contacted customer service in 24/7 chat?

Comment: @Cris I did, but without any success. I guess my desktop PC was blocked by their firewall or some internal issues in my network and router , because after 24 hours I re-gain the access and I can connect from my desktop. But I'm curious what was the issue.

Comment: Were you playing with writing an app using Node.js

Comment: Do you think because you were mucking around with your network so much connecting different devices did it? I don't think so?